# Make gold language badge privileges apply to [language-agnostic]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

The assumption is that someone with a gold badge in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is able to recognize duplicates based on their experience with a language.
To my understanding, this is why they are able to single-handedly close duplicates related to a tag.

[language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) is special in two ways:

- a language expert is likely also familiar with language agnostic questions, especially those language-agnostic questions that are really just language questions in disguise

  - for instance, an agnostic question about "nested if statements" may be a duplicate of a language-specific question "nested if statements in Java", as long as the language-specific question isn't "too specific" to the language
- no one is even close to having earned enough points in [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) to have a gold badge

I propose expanding the privileges of anyone with a gold language badge to [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

Comment: IMO: the wrong way to go about this. Rather than having some extremely special rules for it, the whole dupe hammer privilege should be more easily achievable. And more easily usable across "areas". Trying to keep the privilege tethered to the gold badge *and* somehow add extra rules around it is weird. What if the user has a gold tag badge in [[tag:git]]? Should they also get dupe hammer privileges for  [[tag:language-agnostic]]? If not, then how exactly do you separate "language tags" from others? Is having a gold tag badge in, say, [[tag:jquery]] apply? What about [[tag:algorithms]]?

Comment: There are, for what it's worth, [33 users with \[algorithm\] gold tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1356/algorithm), [two of whom](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2602/data-structures) also have a gold badge in [data-structures].

Comment: How many new questions are we getting that are a) duplicates and b) *tagged `[language-agnostic]`*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not sure about that, but looking through the most recent page of questions, that tag could really use a clean-up.

Answer (score 8):

> a language expert is likely also familiar with language agnostic questions, especially those language-agnostic questions that are really just language questions in disguise

I don't think this is accurate. Take this example: Someone has a gold badge in CSS. Do you want them to have Mjolnir powers over a question that is agnostic about, say, two object-oriented or two functional programming languages?

I do not think domain knowledge of one language necessarily covers domain knowledge of another. Otherwise *any* tag gold badge would be enough to have those powers in any other tag.

Answer (score 6):

I have a gold badge in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and do not consider myself an expert in [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

Let me go further. I do not consider myself an expert in [rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rcpp) either; even though it is R related, it's not the same. I have a gold badge in [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe), and I use python extensively these days. But since I am not very active in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), I will tread lightly if/when using my mjolnir on pandas dataframe questions. If we accept your argument about transferable domain knowledge, which I do not, norms of a tag should also be taken into consideration.

I really don't understand the premise of this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Even someone with a gold badge in [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) doesn't get to close [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions or vice versa. All of a sudden, we are talking about letting "everyone" mess with [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)! Why?

Comment: ez, just let users individually opt-in to what they are an expert in and thus should have super powers over

Comment: Just like collectives

Comment: @KevinB you and collectives :D