# Is OP's stubornness a valid reason to close a post on Meta?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, behavior

There is a user (whom I'm obviously not going to name) who frequently appears in the comment sections of my posts and whom I'm frequently in disagreement with.

Shortly after they join the discussion, I *always* see a close vote on my posts pop up with the reason:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community.

The user has claimed that they are about to cast a close vote in the middle of the argument, so it's not just a coincidence. It's not like these votes have ever managed to close one of my questions, however, I still find them disturbing.

#### Possible interpretations of this close reason

Personally, I interpret the close reason in the UI as:

> This question cannot be answered because it doesn't ask for feedback, i.e. it's off-topic.

The user in question likely interpreted this as:

> OP isn't listening to me, so this question isn't *really* asking for input and discussion."

That would explain them making such a close vote, but I don't believe the latter interpretation is correct. Some clarification on the intended purpose would be helpful.

#### Questions

1. Is there something I can and should do in this case? I have flagged one of my posts as needing moderator intervention explaining this close voting pattern, but the flag was rejected because this was not a situation that required intervention.
2. Is disagreement, or perceived stubbornness of OP a valid reason to close a Q&A on Meta? Hypothetically, what if an OP asks for feedback but disagrees with every single statement commenters make out of principle? Would that qualify, or is this close reason simply inappropriate?
3. Are there any consequences for such serial close vote patterns? It seems like moderators don't deem this worthy of intervention, at least not if the question wasn't actually closed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*(Unfortunately it's hard to answer this question in a way that doesn't single out anyone in particular, however close votes that go through are public and you already drew attention to them with this post, so...)*

In the interest of transparency, I declined the flag you mention.

> Are there any consequences for such serial close vote patterns?

Of course, **if** a serial behavior can be ascertained *at the time you raise such a flag*. I declined your flag because I could not find a **serial** behavior *at that time*. I'm not going to enumerate the close votes you received and by whom to avoid pointing too many fingers against people; it'll suffice to say that I did not find enough evidence to take action.

> Is disagreement, or perceived stubbornness of OP a valid reason to close a Q&A on Meta? Hypothetically, what if an OP asks for feedback but disagrees with every single statement commenters make out of principle? Would that qualify, or is this close reason simply inappropriate?

You are conflating two different things. *Disagreement* is obviously not a valid reason for closing posts in Meta. *Perceived stubbornness*, eh... The word "Perceived" puts us in rather subjective territory.

The close reason "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community." is meant for rants. Now, I don't think your recent questions are rants. Nevertheless, it's possible to imagine that after a lengthy discussion in comments, with possibly some miscommunication sprinkled on top, someone might see your post as "not seeking input" and/or coming across as ranty. Or, phrased differently: that the discussion they are having with you causes them to qualify your post as a rant.

That's too subjective though. You, and first and foremost us moderators, must assume good faith whenever possible. Then, if someone happens to cast an invalid close vote (or two), the review queues are there to correct that.

With that said, I found the close vote on your latest question rather unwarranted, *today* and in the overall context of your posts and interactions in Meta, so I proceeded to undo that one. (I even did that before seeing this post, as the timestamps show, although you probably started drafting this post before then).

That's about the extent of what I believe necessary moderator intervention, **without an actual sustained pattern of vote abuse**.

Naturally, if the pattern of targeted and/or invalid close votes continues, you may flag it again, and if we can find sufficient evidence, the people who are casting these votes will hear from us.

Comment: You didn’t really comment on the fact that seeing this user frequently engaging on their questions like they do, may seem abusive, and a form of harassment. Now, I’m aware of who it is, and have also talked to them, so from what I understand, there is no such intention of being abusive. I _do_ think it would help to take a step back, though. Point is, even though that user has no such intentions, I understand Jan’s frustration. It’s an unfortunate situation. It does seem like there’s more of an intention to win an argument by force, than to listen, understand, and find a proper solution.

Comment: _"listen, understand, and find a proper solution"_ applies to both sides of the coin, there.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure it does, but from my understanding, your early comments should've been a tiny bit more diplomatic. ;) Especially some of them, fostered stubbornness in the reader, rather than understanding. I'm an outside viewer, and can't really remember which side of the discussion(s) I'm on, so I'm kinda neutral in this regard. I'm sure you wanna convince whoever you are arguing with, not appal them, right?

Comment: Sure, but I'll do a deep-dive into the situation, see what's valid on OP's claims, and what's not.

Answer (score 23):

Being the user OP is talking about, I'd say fine, let's have a good look at your recent questions, and see what's valid in your claims about my (mis-)behaviour.
(excluding any deleted questions):

1. [Why is this FAQ getting downvoted, and how can I improve it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426590)
2. [Add language hint to [c++98], [c++03], ..., [c++26] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426587)
3. [Mass tagging request: add [c++] to questions tagged [c++98], [c++03], etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426588)
4. [Are broad tags like [function] or [class] actually useful? If not, what should we do about it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426584)
5. [Unable to edit any tag wikis shortly after unlocking trusted user privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426571)
6. [Remove language hint from [gcc] tag or make [c++] a stronger hint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426561)
7. [Add an explanation of the XY problem to the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426512)
8. [Restoring the original intent of the author would vandalize the Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426365)
9. [When do modernization edits conflict with the author's intent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426288)
10. [Rename [typetraits] to [type-traits]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426416)
11. [Make gold language badge privileges apply to [language-agnostic]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426260)
12. [Can we hide the tail end of overly long answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314)
13. [Masked links with square brackets aren't rendered in comment Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426310)
14. [Can we have automatic pretty links to questions in comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426270)
15. [Add a text field for specifying a reason when rolling back edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426261)

Now, trust me, I've seen them *all* at one point or another, as I'm pretty active on Meta.

I have not interacted with *all* of your questions. I generally only interact if I think I have something useful to say, be it a differing opinion, strong agreement, or an answer. The questions I *did* interact with, are numbers **1, 8, 9, 12, 13** and **this question**. Note that I'm not counting up/downvotes as those are private, but I can guarantee you I've voted on some of the other ones.

Let's see how those interactions played out:

---

1. **[Why is this FAQ getting downvoted, and how can I improve it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426590)**

My first comment there was me asking you:

> Why does something that's very well documented need an FAQ on SO? ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426590/why-is-this-faq-getting-downvoted-and-how-can-i-improve-it#comment973698_426590))

This resulted in a discussion where I stated that using 13-year-old questions isn't very good justification, yet you repeatedly bring up older questions to justify your FAQ entry. I reiterated that I thought the FAQ entry just wasn't that useful.
Then, from my memory, in a now-deleted comment, you stated something along the lines of *"I don't care about your input"*. I don't remember the exact wording, to which I replied with something like *"Fine, have a "not looking for input" close-vote"*.

Petty? Maybe. Warranted? Maybe not. Imho, even though the question itself appears to be looking for input, your dismissal of any and all disagreements from *multiple* users in the comments, indicates you're *only* interested in people agreeing with you. To me, that's very unconstructive, and certainly qualifies as *"does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community"*.

---

2. **[Restoring the original intent of the author would vandalize the Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426365)**

Yes, we've had a small discussion in the comments. I also **answered** that question, expressing my disagreement with the premise of the question.
I ***never*** close-voted that question.

However, in comments on the answer, you repeatedly accused me of mischaracterizing your position. Even *after* I edited it to clarify that that's not my intention, you insisted on the worst possible interpretation of that line, and kept badgering me to change it, even flagging it for mod attention, if I recall correctly (again, some comments are deleted)

---

3. **[When do modernization edits conflict with the author's intent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426288/when-do-modernization-edits-conflict-with-the-authors-intent)**

I added a tag to the question, and we had a discussion on YCS's answer.
That discussion started with me [pointing out a misconception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426288/when-do-modernization-edits-conflict-with-the-authors-intent#comment971320_426301) from you about what the purpose of SO is. Your disagreement is based on what you think SO ***should*** cater to.
That's a perfectly fine opinion to have.
It is, however, not how SO *currently* works.

You kept doubling down, until at one point I let my frustration get the better of me:

> And on top of that, the more often you call SO's audience "hypothetical", the more you insist you're right and everyone else is wrong, the more reason we have to close this, because you're clearly not here for our opinion. ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426288/when-do-modernization-edits-conflict-with-the-authors-intent#comment971330_426301))

So, yes, I did close-vote that one.

But, [I *did* answer the question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426289/1835379)
That answer currently has **double** the score of the accepted answer, and the highest score overall.

You completely dismissed that answer because you think that the situation of a user being stuck maintaining legacy soft/hardware was unrealistic and irrelevant.

Again, you were [dismissive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426288/when-do-modernization-edits-conflict-with-the-authors-intent?answertab=scoredesc#comment971162_426289) of disagreement.

---

4. **[Can we hide the tail end of overly long answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers)**

My [first interaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers#comment971406_426314) there was asking you what a good arbitrary number would be, instead.
Then, [I realized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers#comment971420_426314) that feature could be used to sneak in spam.

*Again*, you [completely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers#comment971427_426314) [dismissed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers#comment971434_426314) [any and all concerns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers#comment971437_426314) regarding the spam.

This was one of the first instances where we interacted a lot. I even tried to explain my stance, and explain that the burden of proof you were demanding [goes both ways](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426314/can-we-hide-the-tail-end-of-overly-long-answers#comment971454_426315).

Your responses there came across as abrasive and once again, dismissive. You accused people of not reading the question, and insisted that a "TikTok" comparison was malicious.

Now, did I close-vote that?

Yeap. Again, due to you completely dismissing any and all negative feedback.

---

5. **[Masked links with square brackets aren't rendered in comment Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426310/masked-links-with-square-brackets-arent-rendered-in-comment-markdown)**

A good question. Factual, I answered it, you accepted my answer.

Did I close-vote that?

***Nope***.

---

6. **[Is OP's stubornness a valid reason to close a post on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426593/is-ops-stubornness-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-post-on-meta)**

This very question.

I posted an answer. You replied with a [wall of text](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56711388#56711388) dismissing ***everything*** I wrote in here:

> - I don't believe you accurately remember or represent the discussions in those posts
> - you only ever join the discussion to disagree with me
> - someone who has arguments on Stack Overflow for the sake of it
> - it's because you like to have arguments.
> - You also show a pattern of thinking of your opinion as much more than it is.
> - You provide your opinion (...), but you think of it as much more.
> - anyone disagreeing with you would be violating site policy.
> - your activity and experience has made you lose humility over time.
> - if you think of your opinion as much more than it is, then a disagreement with it is such a great offence that it even warrants a close vote.

That's a whole lot of lines stating that I should "sod off" with my opinion, and it's a whole lot of you *not* going into anything I actually wrote here.

Sure, there are a couple of compliments in there, immediately followed by a statement about it being a bad quality.

How do you expect me to assume good faith when I'm answered with a barrage of accusations?

And did I close-vote this?

***Nope***.

---

#### So what's the score?

Out of 6 questions I interacted with you, I close-voted...

### 3

That's a large difference from your accusations of "serial voting".
Sure, it's 50%.
Sure, the questions *themselves* were fine.
In every instance, your attitude regarding negative feedback resulted in my close-vote.

I don't remember if there are any deleted questions that I close-voted, but if they're deleted, I think it's hard to argue a close-vote was unwarranted.

So, out of your 15 most recent questions, I only close-voted 3. That's not a bad track record for any asker...

I do realize that I can come across strong in my writing. I do, at times, run out of patience. I do, however, have very little tolerance for people telling "us" to change, who don't appear to be open to any kind of explanation.

It's a process for me to work on that. I'm aware of it, but it's not easy to change.

That said, I'd like to ask you to assume good faith. Don't dismiss arguments you disagree with. *Answer* them with reason.

---

Now that we have that mess out of thee way, I must state that I stand by my reasons to close-vote.

If a user *is* dismissive of any and all negative/disagreeing feedback, then to me it looks like *all* the user is interested in, is a bunch of yes-men.

Then that user is not open to *"input and discussion from the community."*

Then, IMO, that close-vote reason applies.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255413/discussion-on-answer-by-cerbrus-is-ops-stubornness-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-po); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I moved the entire comment thread to chat since it's become a back-and-forth between two people only. If you need some discussion to figure out how to get along well, please continue doing so in chat. Public discussions in Meta should focus on the merits of the post instead of the relationship between two particular users.

Comment: Imo it's about the question, not the user. If there's a discussion to be had, the question does seek input and discussion. If it's just a rant, there's often no discussion to be had, but if there is and the OP ignores input, you can choose to move your opinion to an answer and let the community vote on it, to ignore the OP and discuss away with others, or to disengage. Curating questions should be done based on the merit of the question, not who's asking it.

Comment: @ErikA yeah, good points. Cerbrus makes the point in this post that "if a user is dismissive of any and all feedback", then that warrants a close vote. However, whether someone is perceived as dismissive is ultimately subjective. Whether someone simply agrees with someone else or whether they want "yes-men" is equally subjective. It is very dangerous to use such completely subjective measures to then curate site content. I would go as far as to say that it *weaponizes* the moderation tools that you unlock through reputation. Thankfully there is still a voting system to keep this in check.

Comment: I don't think you can view the user, and the user's comments on the question 100% separately. There's been plenty of precedence in the past, especially on Meta, where a "okay" question got closed and deleted because the OP was acting like a total <insert bad word here> in the comments. Sure, it may be subjective, but so are a few other CV reasons, like "opinion based".